# I shouldn't have asked him.. again

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, visual, movies, sequence

My roommate (rm) always looks busy in front of his laptop, so I try to start talking to him

> Me: Hi, [the last time we talked](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65370/i-shouldnt-have-asked-him) you told me your favorite book, and I like your taste! it's a very good book!
>
> Rm: really? I'm glad you liked it
>
> Me: I wonder do you have any favorite movie? maybe we share the same taste in movie
>
> Rm: hmm...wait..
>
> (he start open his laptop, and do something)
>
> Rm: this!
>
> [image]
>
> Me: wow.. do you like all of them? I think they all have different genres
>
> Rm: No.. *they have the same genre, they even have the same main character*
>
> Me: what??
>
> Rm: and, my favorite is only one, it is on the top right
>
> Me: this.. is.. black..? what movie is it?
>
> Rm: that is the question for you :)

What is his favorite movie?

**Hint 1**

> Me: Hey, you didn't include the source from which you got the picture
>
>  Rm: Yes, it's intentional. You will find something odd if you know where those pictures are from

**Hint 2**

> Rm: I just added a new tag, I hope it helps you
>
>  Me: a [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence)? hmm.. Does it have anything to do with a reason why you choose that Batman movie instead of another Batman movies, as well as that Final Destination?
>
>   Rm: Actually.. it's also another hint :)

**Hint 3**

> Rm: Oh Sorry, I forgot to tell you, I've different habits in counting. The second is the bottom left, so my favorite movie is not the fourth.

Answer (score 6):

I just found out there are movie tags in here! this is cool! And for this puzzle, I'm pretty sure (because it's my favorite movie), He is talking about

> Harry Potter Series!
>
>  as already mentioned in Hint 3, the Room movie is in the second order. So I think your room mate is talking about Harry Potter!
>
>  1. I am Legend : the first film of Harry Potter tells the story of the legend of the boy who survived. (or the main character's name is Neville)
>
>  2. Room : The second movie's title is "the Chamber of Secret"
>
>  3. Moon : I think it's because Prof. Lupin can't see the moon (because he's a werewolf)
>
>  4. A Little Mermaid : There are a lot of mermaids (or Merpeople) in the Great Lake
>
>  5. *I haven't watched it (I don't like superhero movies >,<)*
>
>  6. *I haven't watched it (I don't like superhero movies >,<)*
>
>  7. (the question)
>
>  8. Final Destination 2 : Because the eight movie is the final movie part 2 
>
>  So your roommate's favorite is "Harry Potter and The Deathly Hallows: Part 1"

Comment: rot13(lbhe nafjre vf pbeerpg! cyrnfr nafjre nyy pyhrf naq V jvyy npprcg guvf nafjre) I will give you a hint for fifth and sixth movies: rot13(abgr gur anzrf bs gur punenpgref)

Answer (score 5):

## Partial Answer

So far I have these movies recognized:

> I Am Legend, Moon, Batman Returns, *'insert favourite movie here'*, Room, The Little Mermaid, Deadpool, *'Final Destination 2'*

Comment: edited your answer with the missing film, don't know the riddle yet but it might help

Comment: your guess on the title is correct :) I'm waiting for the next step

Answer (score 2):

### Partial Answer

So far I have figured out that the movies are:

> (14 DEC 2007) I am Legend
>  (23 JAN 2009) Moon
>  (19 JUN 1992) Batman Returns
>  (04 SEP 2015) Room
>  (17 NOV 1989) The Little Mermaid
>  (08 FEB 2016) Deadpool
>  (31 JAN 2003) Final Destination 2

From the list of films, none of the following are common amongst all of them:

> Director, Producer(s), Screenplay Writer(s), Story Writer(s), Basis, Lead Character(s), Musical Producer(s), Cinematographer(s), Editor(s), Production Company, Distribution Company, Release Dates, Run Times, Country of Origin, Budgets, and Box Office results.

I've even tried building acrostics amongst them, but this wouldn't make much sense unless at the beginning or end since they aren't all the same length and aside from those two types of acrostics, it would be a tedious process to create the rest with so many combinations available:

> IMBRTDF
>  DNSMDLN/2
>  IALMBRRTLMDFD
>  AMDNNSMEEDLLN/2

I also tried running a Caesar cipher on the acrostics. I used 1 - 25 as the key and found nothing; so unless it's doubled (which becomes 50 possible combinations if I remember the math correctly), then there's nothing there either.

Oh well, back to the drawing board. Great puzzle by the way!

Comment: Wow, I like your approach, but unfortunately this puzzle doesn't have "steganography" or "cryptography" tag :)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... going by your comment to Metazen...

> The theme is... Salvation from death perhaps or maybe escape

If thats right then I think the connection/answer is:

> "Salvation" perhaps the 2014 movie? or "Escape" the 2018 movie

I Am Legend

> Yes Sam dies... and its heart breaking, and yes Robert Neville dies, both to the Zombie (originally Vampires in the books) but in doing so his cure conquers the walking dead

Moon

> Sam... umm... sam2 at least escapes to Earth

Batman Returns

> Batman defeats penquin and cat woman both wanting to kill him and many others are escapes death in the process...

Black

> Unknown film... no idea if this is just blank or a hint in itself

Room

> I haven't seen this movie, so just going to steal MetaZen's reasoning... Method of Escape (Sorry MetaZen)

The Little Mermaid

> Ursula was defeated in the end saving Aerial from death and giving her new life

Deadpool

> Wade Wilson was dying and is technically still dying but he was saved from death by his mutated genes

Final Destination 2

> At the end, new life conquerored death, well providing you ignore the very final scene

Comment: I like this answer!  That's a more subtle take on it.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an addendum to Blade Wraith's answer, in support of the idea that

> The theme is resurrection/escape from death

In Batman Returns:

> Catwoman repeatedly comes back from the dead (first when revived by
>  cats, later after getting shot repeatedly)

In Final Destination 2:

> Katherine drowns and is resuscitated

I wondered if the blank movie was

> Meet Joe Black

because

> Death himself is in the movie, taking the form of a man killed in a car accident. Later, Death departs, but the man returns.

also

> Black hints at "Joe Black"

Comment: I like your guess at the movie.  Makes a lot of sense given the progression of thinking here.  +1 from me.

Comment: this is a good answer actually, but this is not the intended answer, you also need to explain why he said "they have the same genre, they even have the same main character" :)

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, I think the connection/answer is:

> Death - maybe the Francesco Calabrese movie.  Or perhaps Death Wish

I Am Legend

> Poor Sam

Moon

> Poor Sam again (in a way)

Batman Returns

> No bueno for Penguin

Black

> Color associated with death

Room

> Method of Escape

The Little Mermaid

> Poor Ursula

Deadpool

> He's all about Death/Thanos

Final Destination 2

> Death is the antagonist

Comment: +1, you got partially correct for (svany qrfgvangvba, jr'er gnyxvat nobhg qrngu va guvf zbivr, ohg vfa'g gung nyfb svg sbe nal svany qrfgvangvba? jul ur pubbfr gur frpbaq?) and your approach to analyzing each movie is also a good approach :)